# How does SAS read the @@ in the input?

Tags: input, sas

I am a newb to SAS. I have a sample code:

```
data pressure;                                                                                                                          
input SBPbefore SBPafter @@;                                                                                                            
datalines;                                                                                                                              
120 128 124 131 130 131 118 127                                                                                                         
140 132 128 125 140 141 135 137                                                                                                         
126 118 130 132 126 129 127 135                                                                                                         
;                                                                                                                                       
run;
```

I can't understand what does the `@@` mean and how SAS assigns the values from the matrix to the variables in my example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@@` is an instruction to hold the current input record until the next input statement, even across data step loop boundaries.  (Single `@` would instruct SAS to hold the current input record until the next input statement, or the data step loop boundary.)

So in this case, that will read SBPbefore and SBPafter, 120 and 128, then hold that record until the next loop iteration, which will then read 124 and 131 in, etc.  This allows SAS to parse an input record that is not terminated with end of line characters.